# Efficiently finding a rolling average in Polars

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I have a DataFrame in Polars where each row looks something like this:

```
┌───────────┬───────┐
│ day       ┆ value │
│ ---       ┆ ---   │
│ str       ┆ i64   │
╞═══════════╪═══════╡
│ 2023-05-1 ┆ 1     │
└───────────┴───────┘
```

For each unique date in the DataFrame, I want to find the average of the five highest values that appeared in the month leading up to that date. Is there a way to do this efficiently in Polars without using `apply`?

What if I wanted to the find the average of the five highest values that appeared before that day period? I.e. not just restricted to the last month?

Answer (score 3):

I hope this gets you in the right direction.

Simple example df:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'day': pl.date_range(
            date.today() - timedelta(days=365), date.today(), interval='1h', eager=True
        ),
        'value': np.random.randint(1, 100000, (365 * 24 + 1,)),
    }
)
```

If by last month you mean the last x days, crossing actual months, you can do:

```py
df.groupby_rolling('day', period='1mo_saturating').agg(
    top_mean=pl.col('value').top_k(5).mean()
).groupby(pl.col('day').dt.truncate('1d')).tail(1)
```

If you meant the rolling window should reset on the 1st of each month, you can do:

```py
df.select(
    day=pl.col('day').dt.date(),
    top_mean=pl.col('value')
    .cumulative_eval(pl.element().top_k(5).mean(), parallel=True)
    .over(pl.col('day').dt.truncate('1mo')),
).groupby('day').tail(1)
```

`cumulative_eval` will take every row prior to each row in a DataFrame as its own separate Series when doing calculations. We turn that into doing that calculation on each group with an `over` (you'll see the calculation reset at the start of a month if you look at the result of this code).

To trim down the final result to once a day in either case, I do a final groupby and `tail`, since the last calculated mean of the day will be the highest. If your data is only one value a day, this step is not needed.

To do top 5 regardless of past month, you could do similar to the above but with no grouping by month:

```py
df.select('day', top_mean=pl.col('value')
    .cumulative_eval(pl.element().top_k(5).mean(), parallel=True)
).groupby('day').tail(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Say I have generated a random date in Python using the `datetime` module, and that date is:

```py
>>> d
datetime.date(2015, 3, 15)
```

and I have a file, tab-delimited, containing 100,000 rows of "Date" (`str` 'YYYY-MM-DD'), "Value" (`int` x where 0 < x < 100) pairs (where the date was randomly drawn from years 2014-2023). I could load the data lazily and execute the following polars expression within `pl.scan_csv`:

```py
df = (
    pl.scan_csv("data/file_*.tsv", separator="\t")
    .with_columns(pl.col("Date").str.to_datetime("%Y-%m-%d").alias("Date_dt"))
    .groupby("Date_dt")
    .agg(pl.sum("Value").alias("Sum"), pl.col("Value"))
    .with_columns(pl.col("Date_dt").dt.strftime("%Y-%m").alias("year_month"))
    .with_columns(pl.col("Date_dt").dt.strftime("%d").alias("Day"))
    .sort("Date_dt", descending=True)
    .filter(pl.col("year_month") == d.strftime("%Y-%m"))
    .filter(pl.col("Date_dt") < d)
    # Or, if you want a relative month of time, e.g. 30 days 
    # prior to the given date, you could instead use (replace
    # both previous `.filter` lines with the following):
    #.filter(pl.col("Date_dt").is_between(d - datetime.timedelta(30), d))
    .sort("Sum", descending=True)
    .head(5)
    .select(pl.mean("Sum"))
).collect()
df
```

gives:

### [image: polars expression calculated mean]

Looking at this more closely and breaking it down a bit, executing the same polars expression above but removing everything including and after the first `.filter`, gives:
[image: showing intermediate df structure]
where you can see the 100,000 rows have been grouped by day of date (and thus only ~3,000 some rows remain, with the aggregated values nested as a list under the "Value" column).

And finally, to accomplish what you ask about re mean of five highest values *overall* occurring prior to the given date, then the original polars expression can be used as is with the single simple modification of commenting out the `.filter` line on `"year_month"`, which gives (also commenting out the final line that computes the mean just for sake of illustration of intermediate data structures):
[image: five highest grouped-by days prior to given date]